# How can I solve ACPI error?

Tags: acpi, fsck, initramfs

I found this error on startup and I have also searched for the solutions but those are not specific.

[image: ACPI error]

Comment: Have you ever tried disabling ACPI in boot?

Comment: yeah I tried but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your boot problem is probably not due to ACPI errors, but due to a corrupt file system.

To repair your file system, at the (initramfs) prompt, type:

```
fsck -f /dev/sda6
```

Then try to reboot.

**Update #1:**

You also have two USB devices that are drawing too much current. Identify and unplug them asap.

Comment: Thanks, I manually run fsck then it's worked, but I want to know why the problem occurred

Comment: @srinathsri sometimes file system corruption just happens over time, due to application or system crashes. Do you dual-boot with Windows? Note my update in my answer about your USB devices.